# Transformation from a Wiener process to another stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

Consider a functional of Wiener process $W_{t}$, for example
$$
Z_{t}\equiv F[W_{t}]=\sin[W_{t}],
$$
how to calculate the probability measure of this new process. In other words, is there a simple formula for the transformation between random processes like the transformation between random variables
$$
P(X){\rm d}X=P(X)\dfrac{{\rm d}X}{{\rm d}Y}{\rm d}Y\equiv \hat{P}(Y){\rm d}Y,
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables. If you could provide me with specific steps and references, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A probability measure is something you define (sometimes implicitly) or choose. In this case you are defining a measure under which $W_t$ is a Wiener process. In this context, do you want to know which is the distribution of $Z_t$ at each t or are you asking something different?

Comment: @Papi Yes, I want to know how to calculate the distribution of $Z_{t}$ and the properties of this new process. A lot processes can be produced by the Wiener process, I want to know if there are any commonalities among these processes.